# Alternative to Global Variables?

Tags: python

This is my first stack overflow post. I'm very new to python. I've got a function which connects to a websocket stream and then prints results approximately every 100-500 milliseconds.

```py
def generator:
    endpoint = "wss://example.websocket.test"
    def on_message(self, message):
        data = float(message)
        print(data)
    ws = websocket.WebsocketApp(endpoint, on_message = on_message)
    ws.run_forever()
generator()
```

The issue is that this function would print out redundant information. I only want information to be printed out if it is a new value different from the last.

```
OUTPUT:
200
100
200
200
300
```

I added an if statement to my function

```py
last = 0.0
def generator:
    endpoint = "wss://example.websocket.test"
    def on_message(self, message):
        data = float(message)
        global last
        if data != last:
            print(data)
            last = data
    ws = websocket.WebsocketApp(endpoint, on_message = on_message)
    ws.run_forever()
generator()
```

This does a great job and only print new values. However I have been trying to figure out how to do this **without using global variables** and I cannot seem to find any info. This code never seems to work if I make the `last` variable local to the `on_message():` function. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Which version of python do you use?
Is there no grammatical error in def generator:  form?

Comment: what you want to achive is solved in [reactive programming](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754). it can not only filter nearby duplicates, but also too fast new ones, etc, quite a lot of operators. see [operators-and-chaining](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html#operators-and-chaining)

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use a mutable object; that way you can mutate the actual object that `last` points to rather than rebinding `last` to a different object (and using `global` to do it across different scopes).

```
    last = [0.0]
    def on_message(wsapp, message):
        data = float(message)
        if data != last[0]:
            print(data)
            last[0] = data
```

In the above example I used a `list`, but you could also use any other mutable container, or any object with mutable attributes.  For example, you could make `generator` itself an object with `last` as one of its attributes:

```
class Generator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last = 0.0

    def on_message(self, wsapp, message):
        data = float(message)
        if data != self.last:
            print(data)
            self.last = data

    def run_forever(self):
        websocket.WebsocketApp(
            "wss://example.websocket.test",
            on_message=self.on_message
        ).run_forever()


Generator().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) to have the variable inside `generator` and be able to assign to it.

```
def generator:
    endpoint = "wss://example.websocket.test"
    last = 0.0
    def on_message(self, message):
        data = float(message)
        nonlocal last
        if data != last:
            print(data)
            last = data
    ws = websocket.WebsocketApp(endpoint, on_message = on_message)
    ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: `nonlocal` is not `global`, but i think the OP is not hating `global`, but the non - elegant solution.

Comment: @LeiYang Globals is exactly what they're talking about, and it's the only bad thing I see. What non-elegance are you talking about?

Comment: it require a special keyword, at least.

Comment: @LeiYang Not a big issue. And still better than that hack using a list.

Comment: i think so. `list` is even more ugly. can you explain a little what circumstance is `nonlocal` fit for?

Comment: @LeiYang For precisely this circumstance. When you want to assign to a variable in an outer (but not global) scope.

Comment: @LeiYang Added the link now.

Comment: ok. so it seems `nonlocal` is the cleanest way to solve the problm with least code and side effect(of `global`)

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. I don't really dislike globals variables, however I'm new to coding and would like to learn alternatives to it. The global variable works very well for my code example, however if I scaled this code up to include several APIs and I included it in a very large project I could see the globals become very messy, especially if I implemented a API Handler class.
I tried the nonlocal keyword and it works great in my code!